# I can't use CSS "hover" feature when I set properties on Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Im working on a personal project where I try to set background color with Javascript. However my CSS code that changes `hover` property does not work after that.

Here's my Javascript code that works:

```
titles.forEach(titles => {
    document.getElementById(titles).style.backgroundColor = "#7dd5f8";
    document.getElementById(titles).style.color = "black";
});
```

And the following code is not working as I want:

```
.titles:hover {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #a0e1fa;
}
```

Comment: you're setting inline style in your js code, it overwrites style from external css

Comment: Your Javascript is applying an inline style declaration. Inline style declarations, like `<div style="color: red;">`, override non-inline styles. You could add `!important` to your CSS declarations to override that override, e.g. `background-color: #a0e1fa !important;`. That said, a cleaner way to do this might be instead adding/removing a class, rather than using `.style` in JS. Any time you find yourself relying on an `!important` declaration, it's a good idea to take a step back and see if there's an alternative - they're often a code smell.

Comment: i think its better to write another class with those style, then add class with js, it would be easier to manage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it please. It should work.

I added just one class in css.

```
.titles:hover{
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: #a0e1fa !important;}

.bg_7dd5f8 { background-color: #7dd5f8;  }
```

And js code is here;

```
 titles.forEach(titles => {
    document.getElementById(titles).classList.add('bg_7dd5f8 ');
    document.getElementById(titles).style.color = "black";
});
```